# Multi lines statements with Razor in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, razor, asp.net-mvc

I try to write a statement with [Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine) syntax that use mvccontrib grid where a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) makes statement in a long line. I want to scatter it in multiples lines like this:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
        {
            column.For(x => Html.ActionQueryLink(x.Name, "Edit", new { id = x.Id })).Named("Name");
            column.For(x => x.Number).Named("Number");
        }
        ).Attributes(@class => "grid-style"
        ).Empty("No data.")
```

Is it possible to put the parentheses that are at the beginning of the last two lines at the end of previous lines of each?

When I try to put the parentheses at the end of each line and try to start writing new line with a dot, this new line is interpreted like a text to raw output.

I find it odd that the new lines start with a parenthesis.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to add an open parenthesis at the beginning of the code nugget. Change your code to:

```
@(Html.Grid(Model)
    .Columns(column =>
    {
        column.For(x => Html.ActionQueryLink(x.Name, "Edit", new { id = x.Id })).Named("Name");
        column.For(x => x.Number).Named("Number");
    })
    .Attributes(@class => "grid-style")
    .Empty("No data."))
```

On an aside, it's generally considered better code style to begin new lines in a fluent interface with the dot, rather than the closing parentheses from the previous line. As in this example.